# How to clone deployed changeset

Tags: change-set

I have deployed the changeset from One org to another org.I have done deployement successfully.

org1--->org2 (deployed org)

So I need to use same deployed copy (org2) to another org (org3). How can I achieve it?

[image]

Iam not getting clone Option in org2(after deployement).Any other short cut way to clone it?.otherwise I need to add it manually its really tedious task.

I have checked this link as well:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kw98AAA

Ant tool Usage:

http://www.interactiveties.com/blog/2017/clone-salesforce-change-set.php

Looking for better solution!!

Comment: Just a question: Why you are not trying to deploy the same package from the Org1 to Org3 (anyways, that's what you are trying to achieve by deploying from Org2 to Org3)?

Comment: I know it hard. My org was used with Change set for quite some time until we move to ANT which make our life much easier. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the feature does not exist yet. you will have to do it manually. Also, you might want to upvote for the [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000J9NPAA0)

A while back I read something about ClickDeploy.io on [Medium](https://medium.com/@clickdeploy_team/clone-inbound-change-sets-5c8e076d295c), might be worthwhile checking.

Comment: Ya..I just checked it..its really tedious task!!!

Comment: I work at Gearset (https://gearset.com) - we make it way easier than change sets to build deployments, and you can clone past deployments to other orgs. You can get started in a couple of clicks, there's a free 30 day trial, and there's nothing to install in your orgs so feel free to take us for a spin - could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Annappa,

As mentioned above, this feature is not available in ChangeSets. That said, there are a bunch of other issues with ChangeSets as well.

You had mentioned that you were looking for other solutions. My company, Metazoa, offers Snapshot (https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016YhyEAE) for this exact purpose. You can re-use and propagate previous deployments to other Orgs without any issues. I can also sit down with you to understand your deployment scenario and discuss best practices and such. Fair warning: You might hear a two minute sales pitch as part of the discussion but previous takers have been pretty happy with it.

Please let me know if you want to schedule a chat.

Good luck!

Sridhar